# Changes made in old array also reflecting in new copied array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Copied the contents of an array to another array using mutableCopy, but if the changes made in original array it also show changes in new array. Below is code m using.

```
NSArray *newArr = [mainArray mutableCopy];
[[newArr objectAtIndex:indexpath.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row withObject:@""];
[[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
objAppDelegate.arrayProfile = [newArr objectAtIndex:2];
```

I have to remove the value from original array mainArray, but not want to reflect the changes in new array. Please guide.

Comment: What did you want to happen?

Comment: Try reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785572/supposedly-separate-nsarray-being-contaminated-by-editing-a-copy), that will explain to you what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For NSArray you have to use copy not mutablecopy

```
 NSArray *newArr = [mainArray copy];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy all items of main array

```
NSMutableArray *newArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:mainArray.count];
for (NSObject* item in mainArray) {
    [newArr addObject:[item copy]];
}
```

Comment: this only works if the item's class implements the NSCopying protocol.

Comment: Of course. If he want to copy elements, they should be copiable.

Comment: If someone doesn't know that copying an array doesn't copy the objects inside you cannot expect him to know that NSCopying need to be implemented. you should mention it.

Comment: As I can see, his object is NSMutableArray of NSStrings  ....[[newArr objectAtIndex:indexpath.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row withObject:@""];

Comment: Objective-C isn't Swift or C++. There is nothing like *NSMutableArray of NSStrings*. just *NSMutableArray of Objects*. If he is using `cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item];`, he could have anything in the array.