# Supposedly separate NSArray being contaminated by editing a copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have a TableView with some TextFields in. The values of said TextFields are linked to certain positions in a 2D Array (NSArray of NSMutableArrays).

An initial clean array is defined as so:

```
self.cleanEditContents = @[
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@0,@80] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@0,@500] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy],
                      [@[@-1,@-1] mutableCopy]
                      ];
```

This array is supposed to be kept separate from the 'active' array, so that the active array can be reset on a button press.

I use `self.editContents = [self.cleanEditContents copy];` to set the active array both directly after the clean array is populated and on a button press.

There is a problem where even though I reset the array and call reloadData and setNeedsLayout (overkill? probably), the numbers don't reset. I tried outputting the values of the same position in both arrays and it turns out that any changes made to the active array contaminate the clean array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy` does a shallow copy. In other words, `self.editContents` and `self.cleanEditContents` both reference the same set of mutable arrays. So if you update a mutable array in one, the change is seen in the other.

To create `self.editContents`, create a new array with mutable copies of the inner arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *array in self.cleanEditContents) {
    [tmp addObject:[array mutableCopy]];
}
self.editContents = tmp;
```

Comment: Your solution is giving me errors. the line with `addObject` saying `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'`

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I didn't make it very clear, it's an NSArray. That's a nice solution to the problem, thanks!

Comment: One other note. Depending on how you use `self.cleanEditContents`, most likely you don't need the calls to `mutableCopy` when creating that array. The mutable copies will be created when needed in the code in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I need them to be mutable because I'm changing their values when I change the values of TextFields. Oh wait, I see your point

Comment: But you are changing the values in editContents, not cleanEditContents. Correct? I'm saying you don't need the mutable arrays in cleanEditContents.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you expected a *deep copy*.

The `copy` method does a *shallow copy*, that is it just makes a copy of the array and not of the items *in* the array.

So when you do `[self.cleanEditContents copy]` the new array *shares* exactly the same items as the original.

If you need a deep copy (or maybe just a 2-level copy) you need to code it yourself.